# PHP POST missing radio button from HTML form

Tags: php, forms, post

It's such simple code but I can't figure out what is wrong with it. All other input from the form exists, except radio buttons.

This is my form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"
      method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username">
    <span class="errorMsg"> <?php echo $usernameErr; ?></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password1">
    <span class="errorMsg"> <?php echo $passwordErr; ?></span>
    <label>Confirm Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password2">
    <span class="errorMsg"> <?php echo $confirmPasswordErr; ?></span>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>E-mail</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email">
    <span class="errorMsg"> <?php echo $emailErr; ?></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m"> Male
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="f"> Female
    </label>
    <span class="errorMsg"> <?php echo $genderErr; ?></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submitted">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is PHP part:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    $min = 5;
    $max = 10;

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password1'];
    $confirmPassword = $_POST['password2'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    echo "----------------------";
    print_r($_POST);
  }
?>
```

And what it shows:

```
array(5) { ["username"]=> string(0) "" ["password1"]=> string(0) "" ["password2"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["submitted"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Why am I not seeing ["gender"] in it?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong. A radiobutton must be checked for its value to be sent.

Try checking one of the radiobuttons as default and it should be available in $_POST.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="m" checked="checked">
```

You can do this to test which radiobutton was checked:

```
if (isset($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender'] == 'm') { 
    // Male checked
} elseif (isset($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender'] == 'f') { 
    // Female checked 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just figured out too. Can't believe I didn't try checking it....

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. I was submitting without any values, meaning no selection was made for the radio buttons. As a result, 'gender' field doesn't get really created and thus no 'gender' attribute exists in $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

One more tip: you are not doing any form of form validation, also you shouldn't access $_POST array values directly, you should filter them first as user may input something messy.
For example for username input use such filtering:

```
$login = mysqli_real_escape_string(trim((filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'login', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))));
```